# Sharepoint - Loop through list and get column value

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm having a problem how to build a good workflow. I've access to InfoPath and SharePoint Designer. I'll try explain below:

I've two lists, A & B.

List A:
| Category | Product | Qty* | Date* |

List B:
| Product | Category |

The list A got a form that users fill in. The user can type in a product and leave category blank. Or chose a category and here's my problem. Then I want the workflow to collect all products with the selected category in list B and put in field "Product".

For example: 
User select category "t-shirt". When the form is posted, the product category is set to "red t-shirt, blue t-shirt, green t-shirt, cool t-shirt".

Is this possible? Can this be made in any other way?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Connections. Query the List B by passing the category value in List A.